# Pandas Dataframe drop items where index condition is true

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe which contains Dates  & Prices

Now I have a Pandas Series of the same length of Dates in the above with Dates and a True or False boolean indicating whether I should remove the point.

I want to remove the items from the rawdata where condition is true

```
outlier_idx

Date
1990-01-29    False
1990-01-30     True
1990-01-31     True
1990-01-02    False
1990-02-02    False

clean_data = raw_data.copy() # 

clean_data.drop(outlier_idx.data == True)
```

returns labels [False] not contained in axis

Comment: Could you provide the code with which you got `outlier_idx`? It might be a smarter way to solve this

Comment: Could you please post sample _input_ and _output_ data sets (5-7 rows in CSV/dict/JSON/Python code format __as text__, so we could use it when coding) and describe what do you want to do with the input data in order to get output data set? [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Something like `clean_data[~outlier_idx.data]` should do it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of dropping, select only those rows that should remain:

```
In [83]: idx
Out[83]:
Date
1990-01-29    False
1990-01-30     True
1990-01-31     True
1990-01-02    False
1990-02-02    False
Name: Cond, dtype: bool

In [84]: df
Out[84]:
            Price
Date
1990-01-29  11.11
1990-01-30  12.01
1990-01-31   3.65
1990-01-02   0.99
1990-02-02  99.99
```

as @Sergey Bushmanov has already answered in his comment:

```
In [85]: clean = df[~idx]

In [86]: clean
Out[86]:
            Price
Date
1990-01-29  11.11
1990-01-02   0.99
1990-02-02  99.99
```

or like this:

```
In [87]: clean = df[idx == False]

In [88]: clean
Out[88]:
            Price
Date
1990-01-29  11.11
1990-01-02   0.99
1990-02-02  99.99
```